# How to be sure that a name we came up with for an evil corporation is safe to use in our game?

Tags: legal

I need your advice. We are currently developing a pixel art point and click adventure game. We have an evil corporation in our game and we also came up with a name for it. Now, to be sure that the name has no other firm/corporation we did a google search. There are some that are close to our name but not exact as ours. For example, we replaced an o with 0 and added dots between each letter. Now I have a question for you, how to be 100% sure that the name we came up with is safe to use in our game?

We don't want any problems. I am a bit worried about it.

Also, what happens when we release the game and some firm chooses our name. Personally, I don't care about it, but could they come to us in the future and say that we have no right to use "their" name?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this is a legal question best asked of lawyers, not game developers.

Comment: I just wanted to know about other game developers experience with that. And why is then a hashtag "legal" available?

Comment: Take a look at the non closed questions tagged "legal" to figure that out.